# SQL DELETE Statement returns with Error of Parameter has no default value

Tags: delphi

I'm making a hospital program in Delphi, and I have a button that Deletes the Patient Record, when the Patient's ID is entered. However when I run the program and enter the Patient ID it gives me an error saying "Parameter PatientID has no Default value"

Here is my code:

```
procedure TfrmPatient.btnRemovePatientClick(Sender: TObject);
var
iPatientID : Integer;
begin
  iPatientID := 0;
  iPatientID := StrToInt(InputBox('Delete Patient', 'Enter Patient ID to Delete',''));
  DBPatients.Close;
  DBPatients.SQL.Text := ('Delete from tblPatients ' + ' Where PatientID = "' + IntToStr(iPatientID) +'"');
  DBPatients.ExecSQL;
end;
```

Your swift help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried to run the SQL direct on the database?

Comment: You tagged you question with both mysql and sql-server tag... Which one are you using?

Comment: a) Are you asking about MySQL or (Microsoft) Sql Server?  b) What dataset type is DBPatients?  c) In any case, in your Sql, you are treating your iPatientID is a string, by putting the quotes around it in your Sql.  Leave those quotes out, as in "Delete from MyTable where ID = 666"

Comment: You are going to need to learn about SQL parameters very soon. Read up about SQL injection.

Comment: Can I also ask why you assign 0 to iPatientI. That's pointless. The compiler will warn about that. Did you enable warnings?

Comment: Another thing:  You don't need the parentheses around 'Delete from ...'.  That's an odd mistake to make and the strange thing is, several questions on SO recently have used it in the context of building some Sql text; it's as if there's a reference text somewhere which has this construct in it.  Do you mind if I ask where you got it from?

Answer (score -1):

I belive I know whats wrong:

The field **PatientID** on you tabel **tblPatients** is probably  an integer fileld and you are treating it as a string field.

Try this:

```
procedure TfrmPatient.btnRemovePatientClick(Sender: TObject);
var
iPatientID : Integer;
begin
  iPatientID := 0;
  iPatientID := StrToInt(InputBox('Delete Patient', 'Enter Patient ID to Delete',''));
  DBPatients.Close;
  DBPatients.SQL.Text := 'Delete from tblPatients Where PatientID = ' + IntToStr(iPatientID);
  DBPatients.ExecSQL;
end;
```